# wiredep gulp, file order

Tags: gulp, wiredep

I'm looking a simple way to pass the option files to wiredep that allows me to set jquery on top of angular, so far, it is working by dependencies, there fore it set jquery at bottom.

I'm passing as options:

```
var options = {
  bowerJson: require('./bower.json'),
  directory: './bower_components/',
  ignorePath: '../..'
};
```

devDependencies is set to True, I cannot find any parameter in the documentation that allow to me to do

Comment: answer to this question is exactly what I'm looking for too.

Comment: I couldnt find a way, I just excluded jquery and add a new placeholder only for jquery... but this was a year ago lol, I dont have access to that code anymore, sorry =( @Vladyn

Comment: This is an option as well,but  I didn't wanted to pollute the templates however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up declaring these explicitly like:

```
var options = [
        'css/component*.css',
        'css/global.css',
        'css/main-custom.css'
    ]
```

and passing this to gulp pipe like

```
gulp.src("/*.html").pipe(options)....
```